# HTML Minification kills Reader view?

Tags: html, iphone, minify, visual-web-developer, firefox-reader-view

I was trying to get Safari's reader mode to work on the website that I'm working on, there's not much of information about it, but when pushing the site up, I realise that I cannot see the reader mode anymore because when I push it it automatically minifies.

Is there a way to get the Reader mode to work on minified HTML?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this doesn't make a difference. You don't make the reader mode, the Browser does. Maybe Safari has problems working with minified HTML. If you want it to work just don't minify html. Depending on what your website does/how big the HTML site is, it doesn't matter if you minify or not. You should minify scripts, css files and images, because these take the most time to load.
Have a great day/night (depending on where you're living)!